# What are the minimum input sizes for VGG-16 and ResNet and can I change them?

Tags: python, keras, resnet, vgg-net

I am working on a small project and I would like to fit an array of elements of size (999,13,1) in both nets, however adding that as input throws me an exception where one of the layers requires an input of at minimum 32x32x3.
I'd like to know if it were possible to modify `keras` implementations of VGG-16 and ResNet to accept smaller, different inputs (assuming it's even worth modifying as opposed to making it from scratch), or otherwise if there was a minimum acceptable input size that I must adhere to.

Actually, I might as well explain it in more detail: the input files are Mel Frequency Cepstral Component features extracted from several audio files. `999` represents the 10 seconds of data I have extracted, `13` is the number of Cepstrals I've taken and `1` is, well, the value for that particular Cepstral.
Now, VGG16 requires RGB images (at least to my knowledge), so I could just replicate the final axis thrice and get an "image" of size `(999,13,3)`. The problem is that having 32 cepstral components throws a lot of OOM errors due to the size of the inputs to VGG layers being too large to compute. Lowering the time recorded (from 999 to a lower number) weakens my model's predictions though.

Comment: Is `999,13,1` your image shape?

Comment: Yes, though it technically is not an image per se but can be interpreted as such. I have already managed to transform it from "grayscale" to RGB using `np.repeat(a[:,:,:,:],3,axis=3)` (the extra axis was needed since it's an array of inputs of that size) but due to rampant OOM errors I'm trying to get it either as low as it can or trying to compact the net to fit to my needs.

Comment: So, it's `999, 13, 3`?

Comment: Your data suggets, it's more suitable for Conv1D model rather than a Conv2D based model such as VGG or resnet.

Comment: I see... This may deviate a bit from the main question but is there any VGG-16 like solution for 1D Convnets?

Comment: Technically, it's possible to design custom vgg16 with conv1d. Will that help?

Comment: Yes, it definitely would, thanks. Is it something I must implement by myself or is it something I can do just by modifying the Keras calls for VGG16?

Comment: check the updated answer, maybe you can change your title to VGG16 implementation for spectogram or 1-d data so it'll be useful later for other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a VGG16 implementation for your spectrograms, your input images should have dimensions (999,13), where 999 denotes temporal dim, and 13 is the number of filters.

You can change some intermediate parameters based on your needs.

```
from tensorflow.keras import models
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *




def VGG16_1d(classes = 3):
    img_input = Input((999,13))
    # Block 1
    x = layers.Conv1D(64, 3,
                      activation='relu',
                      padding='same',
                      name='block1_conv1')(img_input)
    x = layers.Conv1D(64, 3,
                      activation='relu',
                      padding='same',
                      name='block1_conv2')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2, name='block1_pool', padding='same')(x)

    # Block 2
    x = layers.Conv1D(128, 3,
                      activation='relu',
                      padding='same',
                      name='block2_conv1')(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(128, 3,
                      activation='relu',
                      padding='same',
                      name='block2_conv2')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2, name='block2_pool', padding='same')(x)

    # Block 3
    x = layers.Conv1D(256, 3,
                      activation='relu',
                      padding='same',
                      name='block3_conv1')(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(256, 3,
                      activation='relu',
                      padding='same',
                      name='block3_conv2')(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(256, 3,
                      activation='relu',
                      padding='same',
                      name='block3_conv3')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2, name='block3_pool', padding='same')(x)

    # Block 4
    x = layers.Conv1D(512, 3,
                      activation='relu',
                      padding='same',
                      name='block4_conv1')(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(512, 3,
                      activation='relu',
                      padding='same',
                      name='block4_conv2')(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(512, 3,
                      activation='relu',
                      padding='same',
                      name='block4_conv3')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2, name='block4_pool', padding='same')(x)

    # Block 5
    x = layers.Conv1D(512, 3,
                      activation='relu',
                      padding='same',
                      name='block5_conv1')(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(512, 3,
                      activation='relu',
                      padding='same',
                      name='block5_conv2')(x)
    x = layers.Conv1D(512, 3,
                      activation='relu',
                      padding='same',
                      name='block5_conv3')(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling1D(2, strides=2, name='block5_pool', padding='same')(x)

    # Classification block
    x = layers.Flatten(name='flatten')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x) # reduced dim for 1-d task
    x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
    x = layers.Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)


    # Create model.
    model = models.Model(img_input, x, name='vgg16')
    return model

model = VGG16_1d(3)
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "vgg16"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_5 (InputLayer)         [(None, 999, 13)]         0         
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv1D)        (None, 999, 64)           2560      
_________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv1D)        (None, 999, 64)           12352     
_________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling1D)   (None, 500, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv1D)        (None, 500, 128)          24704     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv1D)        (None, 500, 128)          49280     
_________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling1D)   (None, 250, 128)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv1D)        (None, 250, 256)          98560     
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv1D)        (None, 250, 256)          196864    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv1D)        (None, 250, 256)          196864    
_________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling1D)   (None, 125, 256)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv1D)        (None, 125, 512)          393728    
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv1D)        (None, 125, 512)          786944    
_________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv1D)        (None, 125, 512)          786944    
_________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling1D)   (None, 63, 512)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv1D)        (None, 63, 512)           786944    
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv1D)        (None, 63, 512)           786944    
_________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv1D)        (None, 63, 512)           786944    
_________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling1D)   (None, 32, 512)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 16384)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
fc1 (Dense)                  (None, 128)               2097280   
_________________________________________________________________
fc2 (Dense)                  (None, 128)               16512     
_________________________________________________________________
predictions (Dense)          (None, 3)                 387       
=================================================================
Total params: 7,023,811
Trainable params: 7,023,811
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, friend, I'll implement it as soon as I can.
In the end I also solved it by lowering batch size but I like your answer better!